# AJAX call to PHP 2 arrays and a string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I want to pass 2 arrays (each containing values from checkboxes) and a string (coming from a search textbox) from AJAX to PHP

selectedCategories and selectedCompanies are both arrays
searchWord is a string

I have an AJAX call which looks like this, I'm not sure if it looks right though

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {
         'companies' : selectedCompanies;
         'categories' : selectedCategories;
         'searchWord' : searchWord;
      },
      url: "php/filteringscript.php",
      success: function(data){
         alert(data);
        }
   });
```

and a PHP file that catches the posts

```
$selectedCategories = "";
$selectedCompanies = "";
$searchWord = "";
if(isset($_POST['companies'])){
    $selectedCompanies = $_POST['companies'];       
}
if(isset($_POST['categories'])){
    $selectedCategories = $_POST['categories']; 
}
if(isset($_POST['searchWord'])){
    $searchWord = $_POST['searchWord'];     
}   

print_r($selectedCategories);
print_r($selectedCompanies);
print_r($searchWord);
```

But it is not working, and nothing gets printed out.
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of  `$_POST` and show it please.

Comment: `print_r( $_POST )` prior to the `isset()`ing, if nothing is there, you'll know it's something to do with your JavaScript variables being empty.

Comment: If you are getting an alert then try to print data.responseText else use the "error" and "complete" parameters of $.ajax to find out what's going on.

Comment: I tried to print_r($_POST) and add in error in my ajax call, however, it does not alert anything. Except if I remove everything inside the curly braces after 'data', then it would work.

Comment: It was a syntax error, there should be commas after each data inside the 'data' part in the ajax call, not semicolons. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonString1 = JSON.stringify(selectedCompanies);
var jsonString2 = JSON.stringify(selectedCategories);
return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/filteringscript.php",
    data: {companies : jsonString1,
           categories : jsonString2,
           searchWord : searchWord
          }, 
    cache: false,

    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

In PHP file:

```
$companies = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['companies']));
$categories = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['categories']));
$searchWord = $_POST['$searchWord']));
```